# Best way to get latest block data?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

What can be the best way to get latest block data from geth ? I mean like can i use a script which gets the latest block automatically as soon as geth gets that latest block. My purpose is to check the latest incoming transaction ids inside each block.
Thanks!

Comment: add filter to watch  for latest blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [web3.eth.filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter) to apply a filter and then [watch](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#watch-callback-return-value) the filter for changes.

The one line code will be:

```
eth.filter("latest").watch(function(error, result) {console.log(result)});
```

You can apply filter as per your choice, like if you want to scrap all the blocks just use:

```
var filter = web3.eth.filter({fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest', address: account});
filter.watch(function(error, result){if(!error console.log(result)});
```

Comment: Hi i tried the above solution but i am getting this error :  web3.eth.filter is not a function

Comment: I am using this code please help : const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3("ws://127.0.0.1:8546");

var filter = web3.eth.filter('latest');

var filter = web3.eth.filter(options);

filter.watch(function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});

web3.eth.filter(options, function(error, result){
  if (!error)
    console.log(result);
});

app.listen(3000);

Comment: What version of web3 are you using? If you are using 1.0 (in beta), you need to look at [subscribe](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html). Note that `subscribe` will not work with an HTTP Provider, only websocket and IPC

Comment: I am using these versions : "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "web3-eth": "^1.0.0-beta.29" , which version should i install to use filter function ? Also please tell me how to install the newer version, i was able to find only one option to install web3js : npm install web3

Comment: `web3 1.0` is latest but in beta phase. `filter` was available in web3 `0.2`. So you are already using the latest version. Since both versions are quite different in the way they are implemented. So if you are using latest version , use subscribe instead of filter.